# Score keeping for a basic Minecraft plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I can't seem to find a way to store a simple scoring system for a user identifier and their score. I've tried storing it in a string and in a file, but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Here's the relevant code

```
public class ShiftGame extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerSneak(PlayerToggleSneakEvent e){
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        String name = player.getDisplayName();
        
        if(e.isSneaking() == false){
            try {
                PrintWriter out;
                System.out.println("Writing to data file..");
                out = new PrintWriter("PlayerShiftAmounts.txt");
                out.println(name);
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minecraft has some config file class: `FileConfiguration`  and  `YamlConfiguration`,  so I think you don't need to use java.io.*, and realy needn't to worry about file writing.

> FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);

If you sure have to log something many times a second , I think you should try to use cache or just make a variable in Java , instead of writing into file or database every time..  I don't know why you need to log a list of which player are pressing shift?

Comment: Yeah, I am making some quick game that you just have to mash the shift button. Thanks! I tried to use variables but I couldn't figure out how I'd keep the username and score together in one variable and then get the top 3 players and display them

Comment: I see, May be you need hashmap~~

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never knew about that, and it seems like just the thing I need. "put(K key, V value)"  Use that and have the key be the username and value be the number, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and use `LinkedHashMap` if you need to order it~